# PHP complex role-based access control lists

Tags: php, security, acl, role-base-authorization

I have already made the database and the php code needed to implement this customized ACL system. Now I have to 'Authorize' the current user, and that's where I need your advices.

The system is based on a flexible permission assignment both to the system users and system modules. It has also some predefined, let say user-groups, with the ability to make entirely customized groups also. A global rule could also apply on top of the ACL, but it has the lowest priority over groups or users assigned permissions.

To picture it better:

Predefined Groups:

1. Limited (No Access)
2. Basic User
3. Power User
4. Administrator
5. Visitors (Sample of a customized group)

Here are the access levels (name / value pairs):

- disallow / 0
- allow / 1
- deny / 2
- allow if owner / 3

Note: 'Allow' has the higher priority on 'Disallow', so if you have user X 'Disallowed' on Group A, but 'Allowed' on Group B on a certain access, so he would 'Allowed' finally. On the other hand, if user X has the 'Full Access' by being a member of 'Administrator' Group, but if he just 'Denied' on a certain access, he has not the access at the end, that means 'Deny' has higher priority on 'Allow'.

At the top-level you may have something like these:

- "Administrator" * "1", which means Administrators have full access on the system
- "Visitors" * "0", which means Visitors are not allowed on anything

My question is how to process these kind of checks? Imagine we have a simple authorization mechanism. We would have some indexes in our `$_SESSION['user']` like `$_SESSION['user']['login'] = true;` and `$_SESSION['user']['id'] = $row['user_id']`, right?

Now, if you wanted to implement this mechanism on your script, how you're gonna do it?

I might check for the global access rules at first. Then I would look if the user has already logged-in or not. If yes, just getting all of his groups, and then looking on the permissions' table to see which permissions are assigned to his groups and his user id, and then storing them on the user session. Then when the module says this is my needed permissions to run, I would look then to see if the user has sufficient access to the requested module or not.

Looks pretty complex! Any helps or advice are highly appreciated! :)

**Edit:**

I'm not using any frameworks. Actually I use, but it's my own. So, there is no pre-made ACL here!

**Update:**

Do you have any idea about an efficient way to prioritize (overwrite/replace?) ACLs?

`Deny` is highest, then `Allow` and then `Disallow`. Also `User` assigned ACLs are highest, then `Group` ACLs and finally `Global` ACLs.

Here is what I came up with that finally:

There is an `Array`, like this:

```
$_SESSION['ACL'][$module][$action] = $access_level; // 0, 1, 2, 3
```

First, I would looking for all the Global Rules `*`, and will put them on the array:

```
// The current user can see the map, applied by a global rule
$_SESSION['ACL']['map']['render'] = 1;

// All the other permissions are disallowed by default
$_SESSION['ACL']['*']['*'] = 0;

// He can edit his preferences, (Owner)
$_SESSION['ACL']['user']['*'] = 3;
```

Then, I will look for Group based ACLs:

```
// User could access the Analyze module, all the methods 
// with Permission Name "report". Applied by being a member 
// of "Moderator" Group
$_SESSION['ACL']['analyze']['report'] = 1;

// User NOT allowed to access "groups" module, let say
// it reserved for "admin" group! - To see the ACLs' Overwriting!
$_SESSION['ACL']['groups']['*'] = 0;
```

After all, I would looking for User assigned ACLs:

```
// User have Full Access to the "groups" module.
// It's gonna replace the last ACL, applied by "Moderator" group
// Note that the order of processing ACLs is IMPORTANT!
$_SESSION['ACL']['groups']['*'] = 1;
```

I guess it would works perfectly, any ideas?

**It Works Pretty Well Now :)**

Comment: Are you doing this in an MVC environment?

Comment: No, I hate overhead! I have my own framework. I knew that frameworks usually have their own ACL! :)

Comment: Is your custom framework structured as an MVC? I don't care if it is custom or not. The solution I have only applies if your framework is structured as an MVC.

Comment: No, it's not strictly MVC, however it has some similarities. You may share your thoughts! I'm sure that would helps! :)

Comment: For you priorities just do your searches through the $_SESSION['ACL'] array in the correct order.

Comment: What is the difference between DENY and DISALLOW?

Comment: As I explained in the question itself, "Disallow" has a lower priority comparing to "Allow", that means "Allow" could rewrite "Disallow". On the other hand, "Deny" has the higher priority on "Allow", so "Deny" could rewrite "Allow". The order is "Disallow, Allow, Deny" from lowest priority to the highest. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I handle it in an MVC environment, create a table with this structure:

```
(id, group_id(int), user_id(int), controller(varchar), action(varchar))
```

Then I use -1 on group and user_id to represent a wildcard, and a * on the controller and action. So in your example an administrator can do anything (1,4,-1,*,*). Or lets say Power Users can modify users (2,3,-1,user,*). Or if you want to give a single person (user_id of 34) a permission regardless of what group they are in (3,-1,34,user,update). If you wanted to store your 0-3 for allow, disallow, just add a column. Then you just check which controller and action is being called and find any permissions that apply to the person's group(s) and to them specifically.

Comment: Yes, I see what you meant! I think that would works well on MVC structures, just let me see how I can put that on my own way ... I have not an exact MVC structure, but as I said before, it's similar! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create your permissions/ groups table:

```
id, group/permission name
```

Then, create your many to many table linking groups to users:

```
id, user_id, group_id
```

You don't need access levels if you're just using group permissions.

Then, in your code, just check the user for the group like this:

```
function checkAccess($pageLevelRequired)
{
  // run query based on current user session id
  // run your query to check if the current user belongs to the group required to view this page.
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: Well, thanks but that's pretty simple! I have this many-to-many style already, but I think I need to work more on the structure, at least in this particular case.

Comment: Gotta keep it simple.  You can complicate things if you want, but if you don't have to (which it seems like you don't) then it's probably not the smartest decision.  If you need something more, just ask.

Comment: I like to keep everything simple, but here it's about adding more features and still keeping it in the most simplest possible way. I don't want to sacrifice features for the sake of simplicity. But thanks again, I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Good, well like I said, if you need something beyond this simple approach, just ask and we'll see what else we can add.  But, I always try to find the simplest possible way as that will usually be the best performing and easiest to upgrade/change in the future.  It's also less likely to break; when it's a very simple algorithm.

Comment: +1 thanks! You're right and I'm agree with you, however I still couldn't find any simpler way for having all of these features all-in-one ... I'll look again to see if I could do that in your style or not :)